# Prediction Algorithms in Statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

Here it is what I'm looking for:

Having a random variable, with an unknown distribution of its values, is there any smart algorithm that can predict the next value of the variable based on n samples of it? i.e. if I have a population of 5 samples for the random variable x, let's say: 23, 41, 35, 22, 38 ; based on these values I want to predict the next value in the iteration (if possible even the k-th value). I have some knowledge on Bootstrap, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics), but since I'm interested to implement the algorithm in a Programming Language, Bootstrap has a high cost in time and memory, that's why I'm looking for something lighter.

P.S. I'm sorry if I made any mistake in terms, but I'm not a mathematician. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I also posted this question in CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224413/prediction-algorithms-in-statistics

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here.  Clearly, predicting the value of random variables is not possible.  If you imagine that each observation is an independent draw from a single distribution, then you could compute the sample mean ($\frac 15 \times \left(23+41+35+22+38\right)=31.8$ with your data) and use that as a prediction.  That would be analogous  to predicting the value of a tossed die to be $\frac 16\times \left(1+2+3+4+5+6\right)=3.5$.  Is that good enough?

Comment: It depends on what model you assume generates the series. The simplest models for prediction are typically auto-regressive models, you can try to look at that.